# Bootstrap seems to not load Jquery properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, loading

I was working on this website, took a pause, came back, and noticed that my responsive navigation stopped working. I think the problem is with Jquery not loading properly, but i'm not really sure how to fix it.

i've linked the bootstrap files like this:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>


<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and like this:

```
<!-- bootstrap files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-   scale=1.0">

<!-- my style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. We need more detail. Also open bower console and run some jQuery code to see if it succeeds

Comment: don't use `http` or `https` while loading external scripts or css files .just start from `//`. many browsers will block mixed content loading. So this will be your jquery source value `//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`. open console to see the error and post it here